# Proxy JsonP and callbackkey

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

im near to finish my app and when try to put in onlin server i find some problems...

My proxy don't work with ajax issue, i need to put jsonp and configure my drupal to use JsonP.

Before:

```
        proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'http://mydomain/json-art',

        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'nodes'
        },
    }
```

After:

```
        proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'http://mydomain/json-art',
        callbackKey: 'callback',

        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'nodes'
        },
    }
```

Then in Drupal 7 put... JsonP prefix: Ext.data.JsonP.callback1

And.. all works fine.

But.. I have 4 Stores in my app, and try to reply this configuration in my other stores. And only works for the first one. I try to change the callback1 to callback2, callback3, etc.. but always have the same error:

> Object [object Object] has no method 'callback4'

I don't know whats the correct way to use callbackKey in my app, pls help me!!!!

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I figure from "[the internet](http://drupal.org/node/606332)", the drupal JSONP Prefix is either a set string to use, or the name of the url variable to check. If you set the JSON Prefix to "callback", it should work fine. This is because the the Sencha JsonP call will auto-append a url parameter named "callback", which contains the name of the function to call (typically Ext.data.JsonP.callback#number#.

Note that your solution is not even right for one datastore. Not entirely sure why you get the behaviour you get, but each JsonP call should have a different callback functionname.

Comment: Hi @Claude, I use 3 diferents datastores, one for artist, another one for places, and another one to the agenda. After that i need other's dataviews with datastores whit de publiciti, maps info, near places, etc... I don't Know if i'm working in the correct way but... i read all of this information from a drupal view in json format.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many datastores you use. How it works is that Sencha does a call to a (any) datastore with a unique callback_function_name (Ext.data.JsonP.callback1 for the first call, Ext.data.JsonP.callback2 for the second, etc), so that when the reply arrives, it knows to which request it is the reply. Sencha tells the datastore which callback_function_name it expects through the callback url variable. So Drupal should respond with something like #callback#(#data#), where #callback# is this url variable, which is exactly what the JSON Prefix does.. I hope this explains it a bit better

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to specify a callback (if it's even possible, not sure) in a proxy. Just get rid of the 'callbackKey' param and it should work. Sencha automatically places a callback parameter when using jsonp.

Comment: Hi @Rob and thx for your answerd, but... if i remove the callback, What i must put in Drupal JsonP prefix ? I try with Ext.data.JsonP and something like that but always give me the same error. Object has no method 'xxxxxxx'.

Comment: Check the request, one of the params will be callback.. use this param as prefix:

`return callback + "(" + jsonString + ")";`